# chrome.devtools.network.getHAR does not work

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying create a simple chrome extension to get number of http requests visible in network tab of chrome developer toolbar.
I added manifest.json:

```json
{
  "name": "Entries",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Give me entries",
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

devtools.html :

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="devtools.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

devtools.js:

```js
chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(function(result) {
    var entries = result.entries;   
    Console.warn("entries : " + entries.length);

});
```

But when I add this extension --> open developer toolbar --> load a page
I don't see any result :(
This is a very simple example.. can anyone please help me point if I am missing any inputs here ?

Is there any way I can debug ?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `Console` doesn't exist, try `console`.

However, the bigger issue here may be that you are writing to the wrong console. This should became a bit more understandable when you'll get to the end of this answer.

To debug custom devtools extensions you have to debug devtools with devtools. If this sounds like a madness then follow these simple steps:

- open devtools **A** for any website
- detach devtools window (using button in the lower left corner)
- open another devtools **B** (while in the first devtools) using one of available keyboard shortcuts
- enjoy debugging devtools **A** with devtools **B**

Everything that you output to the `console` from your extension in the devtools **A** will appear in the console of the devtools **B**.

Comment: I corrected Console to console.  But that did not help, neither document.write. When you say "open devtools with your custom panel"  Do I need to create it using chrome.devtools.panels.create ?

Comment: I took reference from http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network.html  and I have only above mentioned 3 files. I want to know if there is anything I need to do other than these 3 files.  I just feel its pretty simple example, I might be missing any extra file ??

Comment: You are right, I missed the fact that you are not creating any panels. Stick to `console.log` but debug devtools with devtools as explained in my answer. You should see the output in the **B** window.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much - been breaking my head for a good 3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

- create a new panel with in the devtools.js using '**chrome.devtools.panels.create**'
- add a listener to to panel onshow event '**panel.onShown.addListener**'
- with the onshow event call '**chrome.devtools.network.getHAR**'